# File (picture) Upload not working

Tags: image, upload

Okay so I just basically got this code online. 
It works locally (to upload a file), but it doesn't wanna work on the website.
(I've already put the permissions at 0777, for the folder, but it still won't upload.

```
    <header> 
<?php 
function UploadOne($fname) 
{ 
$uploaddir = 'pictures/'; 
if (is_uploaded_file($fname['tmp_name'])) 
{ 
$filname = basename($fname['name']); 
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($fname['name']); 
if (move_uploaded_file ($fname['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
$res = "File " . $filname . " was successfully uploaded and stored.<br>"; 
else 
$res = "Could not move ".$fname['tmp_name']." to ".$uploadfile."<br>"; 
} 
else 
$res = "File ".$fname['name']." failed to upload."; 
return ($res); 
} 
?> </header> 
<body> 
<?php 
if ($_FILES['picture']['name'] != "")   
{ 
$res = UploadOne($_FILES['picture']); 
$filname = $_FILES['picture']['name']; 
echo ($res); 
} 
?> 
<h1>UPLOADING FILES</h1> 
<form name="fupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upfiles.php" method="post"> 
<input type="file" name="picture" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 
</body>
```